# Sorting whole fancytree by title fails

Tags: dynatree, fancytree

I have a js code at my page that gets JSON-hierarchy from server with separate load and builds a visual Fancytree hierarchy at page (i left html page parts out from example).

```
  $(function() {
    $("#tree").fancytree({
      source: {
        url: '/products/ftree/?format=json',
        cache: false,
        datatype: 'json',
      },
      checkbox: false,
    })

    sortProducts();
    console.log('sorted');
  });

  function sortProducts(){
    console.log('in sortProducts()');
    var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");
    tree.rootNode.sortChildren(null, true);
    tree.visit( function(node) {
      node.sortChildren(null, false);
      return true;
    });
    tree.render(true, true);
    console.log('end of sort func');
  }
 .
 .
 .
 <div id='tree' ></div>
```

each node has titles like

```
   1 Fooo
   2 Bar
   3 FoooBar
   3-1 BarFooo
   3-1-1 foofoofoo
   3-1-2 barbarbar
   4 Buuu
   4-1 BuuuBooo
   4-1-1 bubobubub
```

and so on. Page loads fine, it renders the tree correctly and mostly the nodes are in correct order, but at deeper parts 4-2 comes before 4-1 and so on. So I tried to sort them with *.sortChildren(null, true)* and whatever, but it doesn't sort them. I got the code into shape that it doesn't give any errors and prints debugs just fine, but tree doesn't sort correctly.

Note that code snippet has two attempts, trough *rootNode* and *node traverse*, I've tried both alone and together and get the same partially unsorted tree. In my understanding, sortChildren() should sort title-strings without overriding the default cmp function.

Any idea what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is ok

```
var node = $("#tree").fancytree("getRootNode");
node.sortChildren(null, true);
```

but the problem is that you try to sort an empty tree, because the asynchronous request has not yet returned.
One solution would be to call it in the `init` event:

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
    ...
    init: function(event, data) {
      data.tree.getRootNode().sortChildren(null, true);
    },
    ...
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I've fought a lot of hours with this. Where I can read more about this request sequence / background that I would understand the whole picture in the future?

Comment: Great! Welcome to stackoverflow; if the answer works for you, should 'accept' it, ...

Comment: I cannot accept it because i'm missing some 'karma' whatever.

Comment: Gained some reputation, now done. I hope you didn't hold your breath.